# RSS 2.0 using WCF: Adding custom namespace to the rss tag

Tags: c#, wcf, rss

We have a custom namespace we have for custom elements:

```
<rss xmlns:blah="http://example.com/">
```

I'm trying to add this namespace to the rss tag using WCF. Adding an `AttributeExtension` to the feed puts it in the `<channel>` element, not the `<rss>` element.

Beyond string manipulation, how would I go about syndicating RSS 2.0 using WCF with this additional namespace?

Comment: I hate to say it, but you may be left with string manipulation.  One question, why would you want to do this, instead of having the attribute on the `<channel>` element?

Comment: I believe that the RSS standard specifies it should be in the `<rss>` element. Maybe it's fine in the `<channel>` element...not sure yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be that the best that can be done is the  element.